# A sequence converges weakly if and only if it converges in the weak-top. space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

#### The problem is:

Let $E$ be a normed space, let $x\in E$, let $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset E$
be a sequence. I need to show that $\left(x_{n}\right)$ converges
weakly to $x$ if and only if $\left(x_{n}\right)$ converges to $x$
in $\left(E,\,\sigma\left(E,\, E^{*}\right)\right)$, $\sigma\left(E,\, E^{*}\right)$ denoting the weak topology on $E$.

#### My efforts:

I have that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $\left(E,\,\sigma\left(E,\, E^{*}\right)\right)$
is equivalent to:
$\forall U\in\sigma\left(E,\, E^{*}\right),\, x\in U\,:\quad\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}:\, x_{n}\notin U\right\}$ is finite.

#### My question:

It is unclear to me how to pass from the weak convergence in $E$ to the convergence in the weak topology on $E$.

How can I prove both directions?

Thanks, Franck.

Comment: What is $X$ (capital $X$) The same as $E$? And what is $\sigma$? Not everyone has access to the index of notation to your book or lecture.

Comment: Sorry, $X$ should have been $E$ (misspell), and $\sigma\left(E,\, E^{*}\right)$
denotes the weak topology on $E$.

Comment: Assume $x=0$, without loss of generality. Then use the explicit form of a base of neighborhoods of the origin in $\sigma(E, E^\star)$ topology which you surely know.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sadly since I am not from a "pure" mathematics background (only engineering), I am not so familiar with that concept. But let me try: 

So from the weak convergence, we have$\left|f(x)\right|<\epsilon$. Furthermore, that $N=\left\{ x\in E:\,\left|f_{i}(x)\right|<\epsilon\right\} ,\, f_{i}\in E^{*},\,\epsilon>0$
form a neighborhood of the weak topology on $E$ at $0$. I do not
see here how to bind the two statements? Could you maybe give me one more step?

Comment: Assume $x_n \to 0$ weakly. This means that for fixed $\varepsilon$ you have for every $f \in E^\star$ an index $N_f$ such that $\lvert f(x_n)\rvert <\varepsilon$ for every $n > N_f$. This is what you have. Now let $U(f_1 \ldots f_k; \varepsilon)$ denote a weak neighborhood of the origin like this:

$$\{x\in E \ :\ \lvert f_j(x)\rvert < \varepsilon,\ j=1, 2\ldots k\}.$$

Playing a bit with what you have you can prove that there exists an index $N$ such that $x_n \in U(f_1 \ldots f_k; \varepsilon)$ for every $n\ge N$. (...)

Comment: So $x_n\in U(f_1 \ldots f_k; \varepsilon)$ except, at most, for a finite number of indices. This is enough to infer that $x_n \to 0$ in $\sigma (E; E^\star)$, since every weakly open set $U$ containing the origin of $E$ contains a neighborhood of the form $U(f_1 \ldots f_k; \varepsilon)$ for some $f_1\ldots f_k \in E^\star$ and $\varepsilon >0$. (This is what "base of neighborhoods" means).

Comment: Try reasoning in a similar way to prove the other implication, namely: $x_n \to 0$ in $\sigma(E;E^\star) \Rightarrow x_n \to 0$ weakly.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you a lot for all your explanations, you really made the problem, and the way I should solve it, clearer.

By proving the reverse in a similar way, I have that $x_{n}\in U(f_{1},...,f_{k};\epsilon)=\left\{ x\in E:\left|f_{i}(x)\right|<\epsilon,i=1,...,k\right\} $. This is almost equivalent to the condition for $x_{n}$ to weakly converge to $0$. It would however hold only for a finite number of $f_{i}$, and not for every $f\in E^{\star}$. How should I abord that point?

Comment: What you have is not "almost equivalent" to $x_n \to 0$ weakly: indeed, it is *stronger*. $x_n \to 0$ weakly means exactly that for every $f \in E^\star$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $x_n \in U(f; \varepsilon)$ except at most for a finite number of indices. And you already have that: just set $k=1$.

Comment: But why every weak open set containing the origin has the finite intersection form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, set $x=0$ (weak translation is continuous):

We have to show that $x_{n}\rightharpoonup0\Leftrightarrow x_{n}\rightarrow0$
in $\left(E,\sigma\left(E,E^{\star}\right)\right).$

$$
\Rightarrow\forall\epsilon\quad\exists N_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall f\in E^{\star}:\quad\left|f(x_{n})\right|<\epsilon\quad\forall n\geq N_{\epsilon}.
$$

Let $U\left(f_{1},...,f_{k};\epsilon\right)$ denote a weak neighborhood
of the origin:

$$
U\left(f_{1},...,f_{k};\epsilon\right):=\left\{ x\in E:\,\left|f_{i}\left(x\right)\right|<\epsilon,\, i=1,...,k\right\} .
$$

So $x_{n}\in U\left(f_{1},...,f_{k};\epsilon\right)$, except at most
for a finite number of indices. This is enough to infer that $x_{n}\rightarrow0$
in $\left(E,\sigma\left(E,E^{\star}\right)\right)$, since every weakly
open set $U$ containing the origin of $E$ contains a neighborhood
of the form $U\left(f_{1},...,f_{k};\epsilon\right)$ for some $f_{1},...,f_{k}\in E^{\star}$
and $\epsilon>0$.

For the reverse:

$x_{n}\rightarrow0$ in $\left(E,\sigma\left(E,E^{\star}\right)\right)\Rightarrow x_{n}\in U\left(f_{1},...,f_{k};\epsilon\right)$,
except for at most a finite number of indices, $f_{i}\in E^{\star},\,\epsilon>0$.

$\Rightarrow f_{i}(x_{n})\rightarrow0$ for $f_{i}\in E^{\star},\, i=1,...,k$.

Set $k=1\Rightarrow\forall f\in E^{\star}:\, f\left(x_{n}\right)\rightarrow f\left(0\right)=0\Rightarrow x_{n}\rightharpoonup0$

$\square$

Comment: Good, thank you! I should have made our comments into an answer but I'm busy right now, you saved me some precious time.